# Google Sheet join and aggregate

Tags: google-sheets

Given table A:

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.33 | 0.25 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.7 |

and table B:

| date | id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08 | 1 | 0.25 |
| 01/08 | 2 | 0.45 |
| 02/08 | 1 | 1 |
| 04/08 | 2 | 0.7 |

I would like to create a table which joins A and B by id and sums all value1 and value2 for all dates like this:

| date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08 | 0.25 * 0.33 + 0.4 * 0.45 | 0.25 * 0.25 + 0.45 * 0.7 |
| 02/08 | 0.33 | 0.25 |
| 03/08 | 0 | 0 |
| 04/08 | 0.7 * 0.4 | 0.7 * 0.7 |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      B!A1, A!B1:C1; 
      B!A2:A, 
      B!C2:C * iferror( vlookup(B!B2:B, A!A2:C, { 2, 3 }, false) ) 
    }, 
    "select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

This formula only shows the dates where data actually exists. To show all dates between the earliest and latest date and insert superfluous blank data in those rows, use this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      sequence( max(B!A2:A) - min(B!A2:A) + 1, 1, min(B!A2:A) ), 
      query( 
        { 
          B!A2:A, 
          B!C2:C * iferror( vlookup(B!B2:B, A!A2:C, { 2, 3 }, false) ) 
        }, 
        "select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) 
         where Col1 is not null 
         group by Col1", 
        0 
      ), 
      { 1, 2, 3 }, 
      false 
    ), 
    iferror( 
      sequence( max(B!A2:A) - min(B!A2:A) + 1, 1, min(B!A2:A) ) / { 1, 0, 0 } 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Is it possible to insert missing dates? They don't appear when I try this code.

Comment: Edited the answer to add another formula. It is unclear why you would need to show those superfluous dates with no data. Is that an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: Well I suppose it's not a requirement. This aggregated table is visualized to me personally and I just prefer it this way. :) Thank you for your help.